# Django passing objects to views

Tags: python, django

In my wsgi.py startup hooks I create a queue objects which I need to be passed to the views module.

```
# Create and start thread for euclid.
q = queue.Queue()
euclidThread = threading.Thread(target=startEuclidServer,
    kwargs={"msgq":q})
euclidThread.setDaemon(True)
euclidThread.start()
```

The queue is used for communication between my "euclid" thread and django.
My django project contains an app called "monitor" where my views need to be able to access the queue I create on startup.

Previously I did this by starting my thread and creating my queue in ../monitor/urls.py however this was problematic as it would only run upon the first http request to that app.

Anyone know the best way to do this, or should I be doing this in a completely different way. For the sake of simplicity I want to avoid using a dedicated queue such as rabbitmq/redis.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of what you're trying to do, its unclear (to me) how your wsgi file has anything to do with your views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Queue` you are using here is designed for communication when all the threads are managed by one master process:

> The Queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It
>   is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be
>   exchanged safely between multiple threads. The Queue class in this
>   module implements all the required locking semantics. It depends on
>   the availability of thread support in Python; see the threading
>   module.

This is not the case when you are doing web development.

You need to separate your queue process completely from your web process; the way you are doing it now I cannot even imagine how many issues it will cause in the future.

You need to have three separate processes:

1. Process that launches your queue.
2. Process that launches your wsgi process(es), which could be something like "runserver" if you are in development mode; or uwsgi+supervisord+circus or similar.
3. The worker(s) that will do the job that's posted on the queue.

Don't combine these.

Your views can then access the queue without worrying about thread issues; and your workers can also post updates without any issues.

Read on [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) which is the defacto standard way of getting all this done easily in django.